# ASP.Net Web Forms <select> element to trigger SelectedIndexChange event

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a  element which is databound from my dataset. Whenever I select an item from the list in automatically refreshes the combobox and automaticaly select the index 0.

I just want to change a textbox value when selecting from the list of items like what I am doing with SelectedIndexChange event in winforms. I tried a lot but still coudn't figure it out.

Heres my code:

aspx:

```
<select class="form-select" onchange="cmbDepartment_onclick()" id="cmbDepartment" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function cmbDepartment_onclick() {
    form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

aspx.vb

```
With cmbDepartment
  AddHandler .ServerChange, AddressOf cmbDepartment_OnChange
End With
```

Thank you in advance.